# Automating replication in RDBMS database tables using phpMyAdmin software?

Tags: phpmyadmin

how to automate replication within tables in phpMyAdmin?

I know how to replicate a table using phpMyAdmin, but how do I auto replicate a table using phpMyAdmin? for example, let us say I add 500 records/rows in table A, and it will automatically replicate those tables whitin the same database or different database, using phpMyAdmin. All database.tables will resided on the same server.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: Replication between databases.  For example, Table A in a database that might be in Ubuntu Server, in which all data will get replicated into another table in another database in OpenSuSE server.  That is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is MySQL replication, which is a feature of MySQL itself rather than phpMyAdmin.

Instructions on setting it up are a bit more complex than can be copied and pasted in the Answer field here, but there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402794/mysql-replication) that has several good answers.

Basically, MySQL has a replication system built in; once configured changes on one MySQL server automatically propagate to the second server. phpMyAdmin can help you manage the configuration if you wish from the Replication tab.